# Using would with present tense

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, sequence-of-tenses

Is this correct?

> I would buy it if it actually does what it is supposed to do?

Should we replace this sentence with this? If so, please explain.

> I would buy it if it actually did what it was supposed to do?

The second sounds a bit strange to me because it's conditional and didn't actually happen but I also heard we need to use past tense in conditional sentences.

We typically would politely make suggests using "would."

Examples: I would go ahead and try it this way.

Comment: Do you mean to have a question mark at the end of your sentences? It shouldn't be there because they aren't questions. (I know some style guides say you put a question mark if you're asking a question about a statement, but please try and indicate what is part of your sentence and what is part of your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to say.

1. "I will buy it if it actually does what it is supposed to do."

This means that you don't know whether it does or not, but when you find out, then you will either buy it (if it does) or not (if it doesn't).

2. "I would buy it if it actually did what it was supposed to do."

This means that you *do* know that it does *not* do what it is supposed to do. Hence the subjunctive mood, expressing a hypothetical which is not the case.

3. "I would have bought it if it had actually done what it was supposed to do."

This puts the second version in the past tense.

4. Technically speaking, the first of your sentences:

"I would buy it if it actually does what it is supposed to do"

means: "If I were you, and I wanted a gadget which is advertised in this way, then if it does what it is supposed to do, I would buy it -- but I'm not you, and I don't want it. But you do want it, and so (assuming it does what it is supposed to do) I am advising you to buy it."

As for your final question: "I would go ahead and try it this way" is perfectly correct. It expresses the idea that "If I were you (but I'm not, so this conditional expresses a hypothetical which cannot actually happen), then I would go ahead and try it this way."

Hence it is not a command, but a suggestion based on the proposed actions of the speaker who shares his/her opinion with the listener.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In example #1, what if I want to say I might buy it if it does what it is supposed to do? How would I use "would" in this instance? Are we allowed to use "could" with present tense event. Example: "I could travel in July because my exams will probably be finished at the beginning of that month." Do we need to use "would" instead of "will" in this sentence?

Comment: You say "I may buy it if it does what it is supposed to do."